# How can I merge the local dev code with remote

Tags: git, gitlab, git-commit

My colleague create new branches for the project: R1, R2

Running on my machine I have the branches: Dev1 and Master
I did a git pull but the remote branch didn't appears to me.

After trying something I got

C:\projects
if I run the command 'git branch' it shows:

Dev1

master

origin/R1

what does "origin/r1" mean? it seems really is not in machine, just in the Gitlab

How to merge code from Dev1 to R1?

Answer (score 2):

If your colleague pushed r1 and r2 to remote repository.

In your machine, to get all update from remotes:

```
git fetch --all
```

And:

```
git branch --all
```

Then, you will see like:

```
* dev1
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/dev1
  remotes/origin/r1
  remotes/origin/r2
  remotes/origin/master
```

In Git, "origin" is a shorthand name (default) for the remote repository that a project was originally cloned from.

- Found "***remotes/origin/r1***" and not found "r1": indicate that r1 branch from remote
  repository (origin) and you haven't checkout it to local workspace.

To more info:

```
git remote show origin
```

Result be like:

```
 Remote branches:
    dev1                       tracked
    master                     tracked
    r1                         tracked
    r2                         tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    dev1    merges with remote dev1
    master merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    dev1    pushes to dev1    (local out of date)
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

To merge dev1 to r1:

```
git fetch --all    
git checkout r1
git merge dev1
```